# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.allowFontScaling')

Tags: react-native, expo

I just upgraded my expo version and now getting this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.allowFontScaling')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:25:19 in errorHandler
at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:30:24 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.17:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: same man, I think its in the star-rating button and i found this on github but i dont know how to use it, if you can understand please share https://github.com/ide/react-native-button/issues/92